# How to draw a rectangle around multiple views

Tags: android

I’d like to achieve the following look in my app to try and group the views into a more logical layout.

[image]

I was thinking of creating a Shape Drawable for the rectangle something along the lines of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
   <corners android:radius="12px"/> 
   <stroke  android:width="2dip" android:color="#000000"/>  
</shape>
```

But what I’m not sure about how to place the rectangle in the view. Most of the examples I’ve seen are placing a drawable as a background for a single view, not multiple views as per the above.

Do I need to create some sort of ‘blank’ view which holds no purpose but to house the rectangle? How would I go about this?

Everything is currently defined in a constraint layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments all. Thought I'd update this with what I implemented as although the other answers were correct, I still didn't quite grasp what was required, so here's some additional information:

Create a  file called 'rectangle.xml' in the drawable folder, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <corners android:radius="12px"/>
</shape>
```

Then in the layout file in which I wanted to place the rectangle, I added the following view. The key bit that I didn't understand was how to specify the size/position of the rectangle. This was achieved by defining the following constraints to wrap it around the items I wanted.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/unit_spinner"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/time_label"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        />
```

Couple of other points I struggled with:

- Even though I defined this view before all the views it surrounds,
  the arrows on the spinners were displaying **behind** the rectangle. To fix this, I had to use the elevation property on the view, and set all the other views to be higher.
- I struggled to get the position of
  the rectangle where I wanted it using the margin/padding of the
  rectangle view, so instead had to add padding to the views it was
  surrounding. Not sure if this is the right approach - I'm still
  toying with it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout around the views and set its background as the drawable you created.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add this as a background to the Viewgroup where all these views are. 
For eg. add this drawable as background to the relative layout.